# How to list all protected questions?

Tags: support

I know that we can use some sort of queries/SQL to get this kind of information. But I don't really know the exact API nor the exact keywords to use.

I ask because I'm looking for a way to browse great questions, not only by looking at their votes.

So where and how could I build such query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/138642/protected-questions) query on SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer).

Comment: just FYI, that query is always a bit old.

Comment: I don't think that will effect anything, unless you mean the data dump is a bit old.

Comment: I meant the result of the query