# How to list questions closed for particular reason?

Tags: support

I saw there is data.stackexchange.com on which we can query questions, for example, [protected questions](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8973/how-to-list-all-protected-questions). Is there any queries to list questions closed for particular reason? I need to list off-topic questions not about Ubuntu to determine if we need activate migration path to StackOverflow and SuperUser.

By the way, I'd like to know why they were deactivated. I saw a reasonable quantity of quite good posts about Windows (and that's why I need to query them) which were closed as off-topic.

Comment: IMO, per Off Topic specific reason is only available to the staff. If you want to know per OT, Dupe, Too Broad, Unclear or Opinion Based. [Check this for further information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/213575)